# Subclassing NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use this `RichFetchedResultsController`, a subclass of `NSFetchedResultsController` from this [blog post](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/nsfetchedresultscontroller-observe-relationship-changes/). Prior to using this subclass, my codebase have a heavy use of `object(at:)`.

Now I have Xcode giving me these errors:

> value of type 'NSFetchRequestResult' has no member 'RelationshipEntityProperty'

I have code written like this

```
let randomEntity = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).relationshipEntity
```

So these are where the errors are showing.

I tried to do this in the subclass of `RichFetchedResultsController` taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/66297?answerId=191718022#191718022) and it didn't help:

```
public override func object(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSFetchRequestResult {
    super.object(at: indexPath)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error says that you actually don’t use the subclass.

Comment: I have just checked and I am using the `RichFetchedResultsController` subclass. If it helps, I store it in a `lazy` closure property.

Comment: My bad, I take back my first comment. You have to cast the result of `object(at:` to the real NSManagedObject subclass. Or create the fetched results controller with the proper generic type.

Comment: No worries. Turns out that you are right. Is there a way to do it without casting? I will have to do a lot of `guard` unwrapping. It seems to be excessive and redundant. The native API doesn't require any casting. Why can't the subclass do that?

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` is a generic type. Rather than `NSFetchRequestResult` specify the `NSManagedObject` subclass.